# Checking if columns on the right have certain value for each row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I currently have a data like below

```
df <- data.frame( ID = c('A','B','C'),
                  Jan = c('N','x1','N'),
                  Feb = c('N','x1','x1'),
                  Mar = c('x1','x5','x1'),
                  Apr = c('x1','x1','x1'),
                  May = c('x5','x1','x1'),
                  Jun = c('x3','x1','N'),
                  Jul = c('x1','x7','N'),
                  Aug = c('x1','x1','x1'),
                  Sep = c('x6','N','x1'),
                  Oct = c('x1','x2','x1'),
                  Nov = c('x1','x1','x1'),
                  Dec = c('x7','x1','x1'),
                  month_num = c(3,5,2))    
df
  ID Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec month_num
1  A   N   N  x1  x1  x5  x3  x1  x1  x6  x1  x1  x7         3
2  B  x1  x1  x5  x1  x1  x1  x7  x1   N  x2  x1  x1         5
3  C   N  x1  x1  x1  x1   N   N  x1  x1  x1  x1  x1         2
```

I'm trying to identify the number of the value `N` on the months (columns) later than the month number specified in the `month_num` column for each ID.

In the sample data I created above, ID A's month_num is 3 (= March). There isn't any `N` in April ~ December, so the output for ID A should be 0. For ID B, month_num is 5 (= May) and there is one `N` in September column, so the output for ID B should be 1. Similarly, for ID C, the output should be 2.

The data I have is very large, and each ID may have multiple rows with different column values.

Could I get some help on how to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is easier if we reshape long, and make explicit that the months have an intrinsic order that we want to calculate upon. Then it can be one `summarize` based on counting `"N"` appearing past the required month, for each ID.

```
library(tidyverse)
df |>
  pivot_longer(-c(ID, month_num)) %>%
  mutate(month_no = as.numeric(factor(name, levels = month.abb))) %>%
  summarize(count = sum(value == "N" & month_no > month_num), .by = ID)
    
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  ID    count
  <chr> <int>
1 A         0
2 B         1
3 C         2
```

Or to combine with the original data:

```
df |> left_join(df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(ID, month_num)) %>%
  mutate(month_no = as.numeric(factor(name, levels = month.abb))) %>%
  summarize(count = sum(value == "N" & month_no > month_num), .by = ID))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df$res <- rowSums(col(df[,2:13]) > df$month_num & df[,2:13] == "N")
df
#>   ID Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec month_num res
#> 1  A   N   N  x1  x1  x5  x3  x1  x1  x6  x1  x1  x7         3   0
#> 2  B  x1  x1  x5  x1  x1  x1  x7  x1   N  x2  x1  x1         5   1
#> 3  C   N  x1  x1  x1  x1   N   N  x1  x1  x1  x1  x1         2   2
```

Answer (score 0):

First we convert the columns Jan to Dec into logical values, which are `TRUE`,
whenever a cell value is “N”. Then we `split()` the dataset into a list where
each entry contains one row. We feed that list and `df$month_num` into `purrr::map2()`
and force all values up to the month value specified in `month_num` to be `FALSE`.
We bind the list back into a dataframe and by applying `rowSums()` we obtain
the desired output.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df$output <-
  df |>
  mutate(across(Jan:Dec, \(x) x == "N")) |>
  select(Jan:Dec) |>
  split(1:nrow(df)) |>
  map2(df$month_num, \(x, y) x |>
         mutate(across(all_of(0:y), \(z) FALSE))) |>
  list_rbind() |>
  rowSums()

df
#>   ID Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec month_num output
#> 1  A   N   N  x1  x1  x5  x3  x1  x1  x6  x1  x1  x7         3      0
#> 2  B  x1  x1  x5  x1  x1  x1  x7  x1   N  x2  x1  x1         5      1
#> 3  C   N  x1  x1  x1  x1   N   N  x1  x1  x1  x1  x1         2      2
```

I suspect there is a way to do this with `dplyr::rowwise()` that might be
a bit more elegant.